# How do you strip whitespace from user submitted data that is not an array PHP?

Tags: php

I was wondering how can I strip white space from elements that are just whitespace and whitespace from all elements from user submitted data using PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the white space... but I believe you are asking about trim() which removes starting and ending whitespace.

```
echo trim("  v "); //results in "v"
```

Comment: lets say if a tag is stripped how can I stop that from entering the database?

Answer (score 0):

Very simple.

```
$string = " Whats up  I'm cool?";
$string = trim($string);
$string = str_replace("  ", " ", $string);
$string = str_replace("  ", " ", $string);
echo $string; //output is "Whats up I'm cool?"
```

The reason is for this is because `trim()` removes any whitespace which is deemed useless thus reducing the total size of the string. The only thing is `trim()` only removes the whitespace at the beginning and end, so I've added two `str_replace()` which have been set to remove unwanted whitespace, and because if there's "   " (three spaces) one `str_replace()` won't cut it so I've added it twice, and if you want to, you can add a cycle using `foreach()` which will trim it until there's no whitespace left but I have wrote it in the basic form as that's what you're asking for.

Comment: I would use `$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $string)` instead of repeated str_replace, if you need to definitely get all of the repeated whitespace down to a single space character.

Answer (score 0):

> lets say if a tag is stripped how can
>   I stop that from entering the
>   database?

```
$sRaw = $_POST[ 'data' ];
$sTrimmed = trim( $sRaw );

if( $sRaw === $sTrimmed ) {
    // DB insert code
} else {
    // Message was trimmed, show user an error
}
```